# How to add new item to SharePoint list using web service

Tags: list, web-services

I want to add new item to SharePoint list using web service. I use SharePoint 2013. I found on the net follow code, but I don't understand how to use?

```
<Batch OnError="Continue">
<Method ID="1" Cmd="New">
    <Field Name="Title">Abcdef</Field>
    <Field Name="Project_x0020_code">999050</Field>
    <Field Name="Status">Open</Field>    
</Method>
```

Where I write this code, where I publish? Is there any other way?

Source of the code: [SharePoint - How do insert new items using the list web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/86350/1934559)

Comment: Show the link where you found these code?

Answer (score 1):

Try using below code by passing `ViewName`,

```
<Batch OnError="Continue" ViewName="{D0E978D3-4D39-4CBE-ACEC-BCFB22344252}">
    <Method ID='1' Cmd='New'>
        <Field Name='Title'>The New Task Title</Field>
     </Method>
</Batch>
```

In another way we can create Web Site Project in Visual studio to illustrate. For that click on Add Web Reference and give the URL to the Web Service,

Its Demonstrated here,

http://sarangasl.blogspot.in/2009/12/sharepoint-list-web-service.html

http://sarangasl.blogspot.in/2009/12/addupdate-list-item-using-sharepoint.html

Comment: "Where I write this code, where I publish? Is there any other way?" is the question here

Comment: Yes, where I write this code, where I running this code? In a VS SharePoint Project, or xml file? I don't know this

Comment: Yes yes I got to know about your question, here is the link that provides information about it hope this helps, "http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/7655/create-custom-list-using-sharepoint-web-service.aspx"